# Can Nginx act as reverse proxy with a forward proxy as the backend, and how?

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have set up a dns server to resolve *.google.com to 192.168.1.2 where, hopefully, a nginx server accepts the requests and sends the requests to the real destination via a forward proxy at 192.168.1.3.

So the network is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfstg.jpg).

Can nginx reverse-proxy HTTP(s) traffic to a HTTP(s) forward proxy so that users don't need to configure their browser proxy settings to access the sites like google.com blocked by firewall?

Comment: It should be able to do this. Have you tried anything? What error do you get?

Comment: @Rahul I'm quite a rookie in nginx-dom. I don't know how to config nginx for this case. Can you help me out, thanks!

Comment: Simple googling will get you here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-14-04-droplet.

Comment: @Rahul This is not what I want to set up. My nginx backend is only accessible via a forward proxy. Simple reserved proxy to backend web server is sure google-able.

Comment: The configuration should not be too different. Nginx is unaware of whether it is connecting to an origin server or a forward proxy so as long as the forward proxy does its job correctly, things should work. Of course, with HTTPS your browser will give you a warning about certificates.

Comment: @I0ius Were you able to achieve this?